# Saber si un array es consecutivo ascendente o descendente

Tags: java, array

Estoy intentando recorrer un array de [N] posiciones pero debo decir si es consecutivo ascendente (1, 2, 3, ...) o descendente (..., 4, 3, 2, 1) o en tal caso decir que no cumple las condiciones (1, 2, 3, 9, 7), hasta el momento tengo el siguiente código,

```
int[] arreglo = { 5, 6, 7, 74 };
int contador = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    for (int j = contador; j < arreglo.length; j++) {
        if (arreglo[j] == arreglo[i] + 1) {
            //System.out.println("Ascendente");
            contador = contador + 1;
            break;
        } if (arreglo[j] == arreglo[i] - 1) {
            //System.out.println("Descendente");
            break;
        }else {
            //System.out.println("No cumple con las condiciones");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Les agradezco la ayuda, llevo dándole vuelta a este ejercicio pero aun no logro resolverlo.

Comment: Los números siempre serán: `1,2,3,4`? O también pueden ser: `1, 10, 15, 20`?

Comment: MrDave1999, según el ejercicio si el array es 1, 10, 15, 20, .... la respuesta es que no cumple con ninguno de los criterios (Ascendente o Descendente), todas las soluciones planteadas por la comunidad las probé y están correctas.

Comment: Pero 1, 10, 15, 20, ... es una sucesión ascendente. Si fuera: 1, 15, 10, 20, ... Ahí la respuesta no cumpliría ninguno de los criterios.

Comment: En teoría, lo que dices es verdad pero la primicia es que sea consecutivos.

Comment: Ah ya. No olvides de aceptar la respuesta que te sirvió.

Comment: Si, lo bueno es que todas las respuestas que publicaron son correctas, voy a aceptar la que en mi parecer es mas entendible. Gracias MrDave1999.

Comment: Una solución es hacer un ciclo for n-1 elementos y comparar el elemento antecesor con el siguiente, si el antecesor es mayor incrementar una variable para los números descendentes en 1, si fuese menor incrementar en 1 otra variable para los ascendentes.
Al final la suma de las variables acumuladas para saber el orden de la lista, debe ser n-1. Es decir para 6 elementos de la lista, la acumulación de la variable ascendentes o descendente debe ser 5, lo contrario es que no está ordenada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para arreglos con más de un elemento:

```
// variables de estado
boolean esAscendente = true;
boolean esDescendente = true;

int[] arreglo = { 4,3,2,1 };

//ciclo para recorrer ascendente     
for(int i = 1; i < arreglo.length; i++){
    // si elemento en i no es igual al elemento en posicion [i - 1] + 1
    // no es ascendente
    if(!(arreglo[i] == arreglo[i -1] + 1)){
        esAscendente =  false;
    }
    // si elemento en i no es igual al elemento en posicion [i - 1] + 1
    // no es descendente
    if(!(arreglo[i] == arreglo[i -1] - 1)){
        esDescendente =  false;
    }
}

if(esAscendente)
    System.out.println("Ascendente");
else if(esDescendente)
    System.out.println("Descendente");
else 
    System.out.println("No cumple ninguna");
```

Answer (score 2):

En mi caso, haría estas tres comprobaciones para asegurarme:

- Comprobar si es ascendente
- Comprobar si es descendente
- Si no es uno ni otro, deberá estar desordenado

```java
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] arreglo1 = { 5, 6, 7, 74 };
        int[] arreglo2 = { 7, 6, 5, 4 };
        int[] arreglo3 = { 5, 7, 6, 74 };
        int[] arreglo4 = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };

        int contador = 1;

        ordenado(arreglo1);
        ordenado(arreglo2);
        ordenado(arreglo3);
        ordenado(arreglo4);
    }

    static void ordenado(int[] arreglo)
    {
        if(ordenadoAscendente(arreglo))
        {
            System.out.println("Ascendente");
        }
        else if(ordenadoDescendente(arreglo))
        {
            System.out.println("Descendente");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Desordenado");
        }
    }

    static boolean ordenadoAscendente(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            if ((array[i] + 1) != array[i+1])
            return false;        
        }
        return true;
    }

    static boolean ordenadoDescendente(int[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            if ((array[i]-1) != array[i+1])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

La salida del script:

```
Desordenado
Descendente
Desordenado
Ascendente
```

Answer (score 1):

No hay necesidad de hacer un for doble, con tal de ir comparando que el elemento n y n + 1  tienen que ser iguales en -1 o 1, puedes determinar si es ascendente, descendente o ninguno; entonces comencemos creando un método para ver si es de orden ascendente:

```
static boolean ordenAscendete (int arreglo[]) {
    for (int n = 1; n < arreglo.lenght; ++n) {
        //miramos si son diferentes en - 1, si es asi
        //no esta en orden consecutivo ascendente
        if (arreglo[n - 1] != arreglo[n] - 1) {
            //si se se cumple, entonces retornamos false
            //y salimos de la metodo
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Véase que no comienzo en n = 0, y comparo arreglo[n] y arreglo[n + 1], y eso es porque cuando n llegue al ultimo index de arreglo que es lenght - 1, entonces n + 1 seria igual a arreglo.lenght pero al tratar de ingresar a esa posición me daría un indexOutofBounds exception, que es porque el arreglo no tiene un elemento en esa posición ya que los elementos se ingresan desde 0 hasta arreglo.lenght - 1.
Entonces como n = 1 comparamos n - 1 con n.
Para que sea descendente tenemos que ver que sean iguales en 1:

```
static boolean ordenAscendete (int arreglo[]) {
    for (int n = 1; n < arreglo.lenght; ++n) {
        if (arreglo[n - 1] != arreglo[n] + 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

pero los códigos de orden ascendente y descendente son casi iguales!!!, solo se diferencian en una resta y una suma podríamos juntar así:

```
private static boolean comprobarOrden(int []arreglo, int compara){
    for (int n = 1; n < arreglo.length; ++n) {
        //multiplicamos por compara para determinar el signo
        if (arreglo[n - 1] != arreglo[n] - (1 * compara)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Para orden ascendente pasamos compara a 1 y para descendente pasamos a -1 y el codigo final quedaria asi:

```
class OrdenNumeros{

private static boolean comprobarOrden(int []arreglo, int compara){
    for (int n = 1; n < arreglo.length; ++n) {
        if (arreglo[n - 1] != arreglo[n] - (1 * compara)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static boolean ordenAscendente(int []arreglo){
    return comprobarOrden(arreglo, 1);
} 

private static boolean ordenDescendente(int []arreglo){
    return comprobarOrden(arreglo, -1);
}

public static int getOrden(int []arreglo){
    if (ordenAscendente(arreglo))       return 1;
    else if (ordenDescendente(arreglo)) return -1;
    else                            return 0;
}

public static void printOrden(int []arreglo){
    switch (OrdenNumeros.getOrden(arreglo)) {
        case  1:
            System.out.println("Es de orden Ascendente");
            break;
        case -1:
            System.out.println("Es de orden Descendente");
            break;
        case  0:
            System.out.println("No tiene orden!!!");
            break;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numeros1[] = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int numeros2[] = new int[]{1, 2, -3, 4, 5, 6};
    int numeros3[] = new int[]{6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    int numeros4[] = new int[]{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3};

    printOrden(numeros1);
    printOrden(numeros2);
    printOrden(numeros3);
    printOrden(numeros4);

}
}
```

output:

1. Es de orden Ascendente
2. No tiene orden!!!
3. Es de orden Descendente
4. Es de orden Ascendente

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que `N>=2`, solo con ver el primer y último elemento puedes saber si tienes que comprobar si es consecutivo ascendente o consecutivo descendente.

En código quedaría así:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //int[] arreglo = { 6,7,8,9 };
    //int[] arreglo = { 20,19,18,17,16 };
    int[] arreglo =  { 5, 6, 7, 74 };
    int dif = 0;
    boolean consecutivos = true;
    if (arreglo[arreglo.length-1] > arreglo[0]) {
        dif = 1;
    } else if (arreglo[arreglo.length-1] < arreglo[0]) {
        dif = -1;
    } else {
        consecutivos = false;
        ///tal vez quieras retornar aqui
    }

    for (int i=1; consecutivos && i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        if (arreglo[i] != arreglo[i-1] + dif) {
            consecutivos = false;
        }
    }

    if (consecutivos) {
        if (dif == 1) {
            System.out.println("Consecutivo ascendente");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Consecutivo descendente");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Arreglo nada interesante");
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Eduardo, el código que nos compartiste funciona correctamente, me aclaro muchas dudas.